# Reactjs onChange event returns element not an object

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have this code.

```
<Grid item md={4} sm={2} xs={12}>
            <TextField
              label="Qty"
              name="qty"
              id="qty"
              variant="filled"
              type="number"
              fullWidth
              onChange={itemChange}
              value={item.qty}
            ></TextField>
          </Grid>
          <Grid item md={4} sm={2} xs={12}>
            <TextField
              label="Unit price"
              name="unitPrice"
              variant="filled"
              type="number"
              fullWidth
              onChange={itemChange}
              value={item.unitPrice}
            ></TextField>
          </Grid>
```

In my `itemChange` method, I console log the `e.target`

```
 const itemChange = async (e) => {
    console.log("e", e.target);
    setItem({ ...item, [e.target.name]: [e.target.value] });
  };
```

**I got this**

[image]

But I expect to get an object. So then I can use `target.value` or `target.name`.

Why could this happen?

Comment: I don't see anything unexpected here. `e.target` is the element that triggered the event (in this case, the input). What were you expecting it to be?

Comment: to acess the value returned from `onChange` of `TextField` from `MUI` you should acess it like in most cases. `e.target.value`. Where `target` is a DOM node that triggered the event and value is the actual value captured by the `onChange` event

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you are simply confused because of the way the browser prints the object. This is certainly an object, so you can add .value or .name onto the end of e.target._____ and get your result.

You can confirm this is an object if you add to your `itemChange` function:

```
console.log(typeof e.target);
// or even this:
console.log(e.target.toString())
```

Don't forget in Javascript, ***the following are the only things that are not objects***:

- null
- undefined
- strings
- numbers
- boolean
- symbols

Yet even then, they have their counterparts that *are* objects.

E.g [`String`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String) is an object wrapper for a string type. An object that will represent (and allow you to alter) a sequence of characters.

Answer (score 3):

It is an object. But it is displayed like this in the console because it's a DOM element. You can right-click on the console where it says `<input ...` and choose "Store as global variable" in the context menu. That will store `e.target` as `temp1`. Then you can try different things like `temp1.value` and `temp1.name` in the console.